# Jupyter Labs: Kernel Dies when Converting Tuple to PandasData Frame

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have the following tuple that I'm trying to create a data frame out of:

```
testing = 
([datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 5, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 5, 2, 40),
  datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 5, 5, 20),
  datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 5, 8, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 5, 10, 40),
  datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 5, 13, 20),
  datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 5, 16, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 5, 18, 40),
  datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 5, 21, 20),
  datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 6, 0, 0)],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

I use this snippet to create a data frame:

```
df_testing = pd.DataFrame(testing)
df_testing.head()
```

However, this causes the kernel to die every time. If i only loop at 1 item (e.g. I do df_testing = pd.DataFrame(testing[0])), the code runs fine.

**I'm not super familiar with using tuples so is there some type of property that inhibits them from being turned into a data frame?**

**NOTE:**
There is a lot of code that generates that this "testing variable" it's just a portion of the overall data I would like to eventually convert. I filled in some dummy data for the example here. I would prefer not to modify the data type of this variable if at all possible.

Also I'm running Python 3.7 in case that matters.

EDIT:
Here is a screenshot of my trying to run the test code I put in.
[image: Dead Kernel]

Comment: Does it die with the code snippet you posted? Works fine for me

Answer (score 2):

I just ran your exact code (pay attention you wrote different variable names - test vs testing).

After changing the variable names it worked just fine:

[image]

I guess the problem is with your jupyter Labs installation.

Comment: I think OP is not looking for this

Comment: Hello, I accidentally messed up when typing it in my there. in my actual code it's correct. I tried running it with the code I posted and the Kernel died. Please see my attached edit.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
new_df = pd.Series(dict(zip(*test))).to_frame('name_column')
print(new_df)
```

or

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'name_column':dict(zip(*test))})
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
                     name_column
2020-02-05 00:00:00            1
2020-02-05 02:40:00            2
2020-02-05 05:20:00            3
2020-02-05 08:00:00            4
2020-02-05 10:40:00            5
2020-02-05 13:20:00            6
2020-02-05 16:00:00            7
2020-02-05 18:40:00            8
2020-02-05 21:20:00            9
2020-02-06 00:00:00           10
```

You could use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) if you want convert index in column

Another option is [`DataFrame.transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(test,index=['Date','values']).T
print(new_df)
                 Date values
0 2020-02-05 00:00:00      1
1 2020-02-05 02:40:00      2
2 2020-02-05 05:20:00      3
3 2020-02-05 08:00:00      4
4 2020-02-05 10:40:00      5
5 2020-02-05 13:20:00      6
6 2020-02-05 16:00:00      7
7 2020-02-05 18:40:00      8
8 2020-02-05 21:20:00      9
9 2020-02-06 00:00:00     10
```

Comment: The issue with this method is I need to create multiple sets of data frames in a loop. That's why I don't want to have to change the data type.

Comment: you method would work it's just not the solution for me. Thanks for the feedback!